# Hover delay within multiple event function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this multiple event function

```
$('.loaded.mega-menu-item').on({
    hover: function(){
       $('.mega-content',this).css('display','block');
    },
    click: function(){
        $('.mega-content',this).css('display','block');
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $('.mega-content',this).css('display','none');
    }
});
```

and I want to do a 'hover intent' of 300ms.
I tried to place a setTimeOut but It didn't work.

Maybe the way I wrote the function is not the best, any help will be useful.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, why not use the fadeIn() method?

Comment: Could you paste the code whit that change please? I don't know how to implement it and to have the same effect as mine

Answer (score 0):

You can use hover() function:

```
$(element).hover(function(){},function(){});
```

and your code will look like this:

```
$('.loaded.mega-menu-item').hover(function(){
 $('.mega-content',this).fadeIn(300);
},function(){
$('.mega-content',this).fadeOut(300);
});
```

Comment: Yes, that would be in a single implementation, but how do to that in my case that I have 3 event handlers :/ ... or at least something that works the same

Comment: @LesterVargas you can use another click() event inside hover in function.

Comment: Could you post that as an answer to try it out